# Remove ampersand node.js POST request

Tags: node.js, http

I have an express version 
`"express": ">= 3.4.7"` in my packager.json file 
using `app.use(express.cookieParser())` in configuration. 
Am sending a post request 
to my API's from REST client content type as `"application/json"`.

I used to get post parameters by calling req.body.

Everything working for me till now, but noticed when sending something like following

```
{
  "password":"tom&catin",
}
```

In node js

```
 console.log('password', req.body.password); // tom&amp;catin
```

I want to know why '&' is printing  as '&'. I would like to get '&' as '&' for server side password 
verification. 
Let me know what am doing wrong? Do I need to implement 'urlencode'?

I have tried but same result.

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

[image]

Comment: Your password is urlencoded and that's expected I believe. Are you using bodyParser.urlencoded?

Comment: No body parser is used. My express version is 3.0

Comment: have you found a solution to your problem ? having same issue here...